Using fingerprint authentication only for contactless payment (especially Google Pay)
I'm using a recently bought Samsung Galaxy S23FE. I mostly bought it because my previous phone didn't have NFC and couldn't be used for contactless payment.
What I'd like to do, is to use the fingerprint sensor to authorize payments, and only for payments. I haven't found how to make either Google Pay itself or the phone's payment feature require fingerprint. The only thing I found is to have it require unlocking the phone (for which I don't want to use fingerprints).
So right now I have to type my unlock code everytime I use my phone to pay, which is much less practical than tapping my finger on the reader.
Is it even possible to do what I'm looking for? If it is, how can I do it and what did I do wrong?

For security reasons apps can not directly use fingerprint sensor, only trigger an authentication by the system which then compares the fingerprints with the enrolled finger print data. The only way to enroll fingerprints is to my knowledgein security settings for lock screen. Technically the lock screen could of course fingerprint unlocking, but there is no such setting. May an MDM can configure the device to disallow fingerprint usage gor lock screen but I have not checked that.

AFAIK, on Samsung/OneUI, it's possible to register fingerprints for biometric authorization but turning off fingerprint unlock. At the very least, I tested it's possible on Galaxy M12, Android 14, with a local Indonesian bank app. However, I can't test Google Pay/Wallet because it's not available in my country. If the app asks for screen lock verification instead, then I believe it's linked to the security setting, which requires fingerprint unlock to be enabled...

I fail to see how this is going to work. You have to unlock the phone to use Google Pay. You want to unlock the phone, but not unlock it, just to use one app.
The workaround is.

Enable fingerprint unlock
When the unlock screen pops up
If you want to use Gpay, use the fingerprint
If you just want to unlock, swipe the fingerprint symbol twice, it will pop up with the numbers.


In my understanding Nathan doesn't want to have a phone that is unlockable via fingerprint. May be because it is easier to force you to press you finger onto the sensor (or create a fake finger with your fingerprint) than forcing you to reveal your pin code.

Call me paranoid but @Robert got it right, on top of the fact that I can easily change my PIN codes, but less so my fingerprints. That's why I'd rather not allow unlocking my phone with biometrics, but I'd still like the convenience for contactless payment (since my card is in my wallet right next to my phone anyway)
